# WebBrowser created dynamically doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'd like to create WebBrowser control programically in my code and then read page content.
I think I'm doing the same thing as designer does but control dynamically created doesn't work (DocumentText return empty string)

What I'm doing wrong?

**Edit 2:** Code change after @Axarydax suggestion (working)

Main block code:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser { Name = "myBrowser"};
browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
browser.Navigate("www.google.com");
while (pageLoaded == false)
{
  Thread.Sleep(500);       // pageLoaded is local field
  Application.DoEvents();  // didn't wotk without this...
}
Console.WriteLine(browser.DocumentText);
```

Event Handler code:

```
void browser_DocumentCompleted (object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e )
{ 
    pageLoaded = true; 
}
```

Comment: now you forgot to let the browser know about DocumentCompleted event -> add browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted) to Main method

Comment: I've got it - just forgot paste this line of code.
But I've finally sorted this out by adding Application.DoEvents(); command in while loop. Thanks for directing me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate method is asynchronous, so you should wait for NavigationComplete event to be fired.
Though, if you want HTML of the page, use System.Net.WebClient.

Comment: I've changed code according your suggestion - still doesnt work - any idea how to fix it?

Comment: heartly thanx, for this post, it helped me a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

The `Navigate` method works asynchronously, so the page loads in the background and there's no text when you access the `DocumentText` property.

Try adding a handler to the [`DocumentCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event and moving your `Console.WriteLine(browser.DocumentText)` call there.

Comment: I need to 'wait' in my main program thread to process read content.  I've add Edit#1 to my example trying archive that. Any idea how to manage that?

Comment: If all you need is the HTML source for the page, follow Axarydax's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pump messages for the events to fire. Blocking the message pump with a while loop lacking message dispatching (e.g. Application.DoEvents) won't work.